# Keeping web part on top of the page

Tags: web-part, branding

How do you display a web part on top of the page so its always there even when scrolling down?

I am trying to achieve this in Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the CSS positioning property `position: fixed` on the web part to keep the web part in a static position on the page. First, add the web part you're using to wherever you want it to be on the page, then find the ID of the web part using Chrome, Firefox, or Internet Explorer developer tools, and then set the CSS property either through a stylesheet or by using something like jQuery and adding it to a Script Editor Web Part on the same page.

Here's an example using jQuery in a Script Editor web part for a web part with the ID of `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2` :

```
<script src="/location-of-your-jquery-file/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2").css("position", "fixed");

    });

 </script>
```